# Verilog module for a smoke detector and a buzzer

Tags: module, verilog, fpga, intel-fpga

I have Altera DE2-115 FPGA and I try to self-learn Verilog. I decided to make a smoke detector and whenever it smells smoke the buzzer rings (*the smoke detector outputs a digital signal*).

Here is my trial :

```
module fire(flag,clock,reset,fire,fire_state,firealarm);
  input        clock, reset, flag, fire;
  output [2:0] fire_state;
  output       firealarm; 

  wire         fire;
  reg    [2:0] fire_state;

  assign firealarm = (fire_state == 1) ? (flag ? 0 : 1) : 0;

  always @ (posedge clock)
    fire_state<= fire ? 1: 0;

end module
```

But it doesn't run and I think there are a lot of logic errors in this code, any help please? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`endmodule` is one word, you need to remove the space.

Almost all simulators these days support verilog-2001 or greater so I would encourage the use of the modern port style (ANSI) and not the old verilog 1995 style.

Your port list goes from:

```
module fire(flag,clock,reset,fire,fire_state,firealarm);
input clock, reset, flag, fire;
output [2:0] fire_state;
output firealarm; wire fire;reg[2:0] fire_state;
```

to :

```
module fire(
  input            clock,
  input            reset,
  input            flag,
  input            fire,
  output reg [2:0] fire_state,
  output           firealarm
);
```

I have placed each port on a new line with it direction, this makes it much easier to maintain code, it also make it a lot more readable and therefore minimises the chance of typos in connections.

You have used this syntax a lot (`flag?0:1`), where you using a boolean to select a boolean there is no need to do this and makes it more difficult to read. If you need to invert it then is a bitwise invert (`~`). However it is not clear what you are using flag for.
for comparrisons and assignments you should be including the width.

```
assign firealarm = (fire_state == 3'b1)? (~flag) : 1'b0;
```

This could also be written out in a combinatorial always block:

```
always @* begin
  if (fire_state==3'b001) begin
    firealaram = ~flag;
  else begin
    firealaram = 1'b0;
  end
end
```

fire is 1 bit, fire_state is 3 bits.

```
always @ (posedge clock) begin
  fire_state <= {2'b0, fire};
end
```